# Whose name is Minkowski 92 bearing?

Tags: nebula

[Minkowski 92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1-92) is a protoplanetary nebula. But after which Minkowski is it named? Same question for Minkowski's object (part of [NGC 541](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGC_541)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rudolf Minkowski.

Its not likely to be the mathematician, Hermann. Nor the physiologist Oskar.  There's only one Minkowski who was an observational astronomer.

The paper describing M1-92 was https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/125855

The 2006 paper on Minkowski's object ([Croft et al](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/505526)) cites [Minkowski, R. 1958, PASP, 70, 143](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1958PASP...70..143M/0000143.000.html)

Comment: The lunar crater Minkowski is named after him and his uncle. Maybe the two objects are also named after him and his uncle? Or just after him?

Comment: No. after him alone. He discovered them, published the first description of them.  Hermann had nothing to do with these objects!  Objects are not named in "honour" of people (like craters *are*) These names are purely "object discovered by" type names.